# why does output of an address of pointer is different?

Tags: c++, pointers

i am confused concerning out of an program
consider we have a class like below:

```
#ifndef SOMECLASS
#define SOMECLASS
class SomeClass
{
    public:
        SomeClass();
        SomeClass(int);
        ~SomeClass();
        void foo(const int&);
}
#endif
```

and its implementation....

so in main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    SomeClass* smc=new SomeClass();
    cout<<smc<<"--"<<&smc<<"--"<<&*smc; 
}
```

and my output a thing like below:

```
0xf66210----0x7ffd622a34f0----0xf66210
```

why does it difference among smc and &smc and &*smc?
note that smc and &*smc are equal.

i am using ubuntu(14.04_x64) and+cmake(2.18)+gcc(4.8.4)

Comment: Why would you expect the address of an object to be equal to the address of a pointer to this object? The object and the pointer to it are different objects, do they have different addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are two variables here :
1. the pointer, which is stack allocated
2. the object, which is heap allocated

`smc` is the address of the actual object, which exists on the heap.
consequently, `&*smc` dereferences the address, then references it again, yealding the same result. remember , `*` and `&` are like opposite operators, like plus and minus. adding and subtracing the same amount yealds the same result, just like dereferencing and referencing again.

`&smc` is the address of the pointer variable, which sits on the stack.

if it's still not clear to you, think about the following example:

```
int* x = nullptr;
```

what is `x` value? and what is `&x`?

and now?
`x = new int(6)`
what is the new value of x? and what is it's address?

Comment: ok, and is smc and *smc same? does *smc->foo(); and smc->foo() has any difference?

Comment: +1 for the nullptr example. @mehdi They are not the same. In fact (*smc)->foo() will cause an error, since you are aplying operator -> to a non-pointer type. If you would have asked if (*smc).foo() and smc->foo() are the same, then yes, they are the same. The operator-> dereferences the pointer and accesses the member foo. This can be also achieved by dereferencing (using the *) and accesing the member via ".".

Comment: Last note about your question * smc->foo() is invalid here, since the operator-> takes precedence against operator *, so this statement would dereference smc implicitly, access and execute foo() member, and dereference its result. Thus, you have to use parenthesis: ( * smc)->foo()

Answer (score 7):

`smc` is the value of the pointer `smc`, which is the address of what `smc` is pointing to.

`&smc` is the address of the pointer `smc` itself.

`&*smc` is the address of what `smc` is pointing to (the being pointed to is `*smc`), so it is the same as `smc`.

Comment: and is smc and *smc same? does *smc->foo(); and smc->foo() has any difference?

Comment: `smc` and `*smc` are not the same, `smc` is a pointer, `*smc` is what the pointer is pointing to (an instance of `SomeClass`). `smc->foo()` means calling the member function `foo()` of that instance, `*smc->foo()` is illegal according to your code. It's better to read [a book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the above, it can be said that:

- `smc` shows the address stored in the pointer (the address of the dynamically allocated (*heap*) memory using `new`)
- `&smc` shows the address of the pointer itself
- `*smc` shows the content of the address (access to the members of the object - of `class SomeClass`)
- `&*smc` points to same address as `smc`(*"alias"* of the pointer, i.e. same as `smc` )

Answer (score 1):

A little bit more explanation.
So basically `smc` is a variable right? (a pointer, but a variable still).
So `&smc` gives you the *address of this variable*.

Now, if you try to print value of just `smc` what should you get? value of the variable right? Since this is a pointer, in this case the value of this variable is address of another object to which it points.

Similarly `&*smc` - dereferences the pointer and gives you back address of the object dereferenced, which is similar as above value.

Comment: ok good explantion...but why does in c++ smc and *smc is same?! smc->foo(); and *smc->foo();

Comment: @mehdi:they are not the same. With printing function address might be different, I think that's not even possible, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111969/how-to-print-member-function-address-in-c